# how do I fix these desktop icons in windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

I can only describe it with a photo:

[image]

The folder overlay area is yuuuge, like 2x horizontal, I just want it small square default sized again. And I don't remember how I turned it on, but I hid my icons to deal with it, so now I'd like to just fix it, any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently its a registry value I need to change in a couple spots one for IconSpacing value:

[image]

and another for the IconVerticalSpacing value:

[image]

I found the answer [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-10-change-desktop-spacing/)